# How to pass curly bracket ({) as a string in f-string python?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, string

due to these bracket `{` and `}` in `Hourly Status','{',''),'}','')` causing the syntax error in query .How to pass these bracket as string in a f-string format?

```
query = f"""Select fd.serial_number,txidkey,cast(replace(replace(data->>'Hourly Status','{',''),'}','') as text) as description,TO_TIMESTAMP(TIME/1000+19800) as date_time,time,total_min from filter_data fd , total_sum ts
where fd.serial_number = ts.serial_number
and time between {yesterday10PM*1000} and {today6AM*1000}'''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use double curly braces `{{`:

```py
query = f"""\
Select fd.serial_number, txidkey, cast(\
replace(replace(data->>'Hourly Status','{{',''),'}}','') as text) \
as description,TO_TIMESTAMP(TIME/1000+19800) as date_time,time,total_min \
from filter_data fd , total_sum ts \
where fd.serial_number = ts.serial_number \
and time between {yesterday10PM*1000} and {today6AM*1000}
'''
```

You can also read about formatted strings here:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals

Comment: You always should use prepared statements